# Creating a sample application where Django Bulk Writes to Mongo Db after Sessions end

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I want to be able to use Django Sessions and Mongo DB together to perform bulk writes to database after a Session. Later I want to be able to associate Users to Sessions and Events as well.

I have just started and I am new to Django . I am just running around tutorial after tutorial and so far I have just tried out some things and may have got a few things right I guess.

Any help with finding some right direction is appreciated.

Here is my views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
import json

class Events(APIView):
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        try:
            event_info = json.loads(request.body)
        except ValueError:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        if not request.session.session_key:
            request.session.save()
        sid = str(request.session.session_key)
        settings.DB.events.insert(event_info, w=1)          
        return Response(sid,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

events = Events.as_view()
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.conf  import settings
# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

class EventsModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
        self.db = conn.dev_db

    def save(self, event_info):
        """
            Save json object into mongodb Cluster
        :param event_info:
        :return:
        """
        self.db.events.insert(event_info, w=1)
```

Comment: Why not using https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine  ?

Comment: @Sergiu Zaharie . Will try this now.